# What effect does answering the phone from the "Future happiness committee" do?

Tags: the-stanley-parable

On one of my playthroughs, the phone on desk 434 rang, so I answered it:

[image]

It was from the "Future Happiness Committee" and they wanted to confirm an order of 1300-some-odd boxes. I had assumed that was going to be important later on in the game, but nothing came of it.

Does confirming this order affect any portion of the game in the future?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it doesn't, the phone call is also random sometime it's your wife who is calling. If you reach an ending after having asnwered to the "Future Happiness Committee", on the next spawn the office will be filled with those boxes but this is nothing more than a random event in the game.

Note that to get the boxes to spawn, you have to listen to the entire message, and then use the phone again to respond and confirm the order.  So if you didn't get the boxes the first time this happened, you probably didn't confirm the order of boxes.